# APTonCD equivalent for Fedora

Tags: fedora, package-management, yum, data-cd

Is there an equivalent of APTonCD for Fedora? I tried googling and found [YUMonCD](https://bitbucket.org/a_atalla/yumoncd/downloads/) but wanted to know if there exists some package in the repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YUMonCD page you linked to provides RPM packages, why not use those?

Comment: Figured out that there doesn't seem to be any other option so finally using it now. :)