# Backup installed RPM

Tags: fedora, rpm

Last night I did `rm -Rf /tmp` as root. I wasn't drunk. But I definitely feel I was dumb to do so. Now X doesn't work. I read few days back that after doing `rm`, one can't recover the lost data. I mounted a USB stick but it doesn't show up in `/media` directory. I need to backup the data in `/home` folder. I think I can recover that data by some live usb.

Is there a way to backup the rpms that are installed on Fedora machine? I wish to save bandwidth. So if it's possible, I'd prefer saving all the installed rpms in a directory and then re-installing them simply by doing `rpm -i`. I earlier posted [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10973/aptoncd-equivalent-for-fedora) question but YUMonCD package doesn't work fine on my Fedora 14. I found [this](http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/keep-a-backup-of-installed-packages/) to create a list of installed rpms and then re-installing it after formating. But it doesn't save any bandwidth for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just recreating the /tmp directory with proper permissions should do the trick.

`mkdir /tmp`
`chmod 777 /tmp`
`chmod +t /tmp`

`/tmp` does not contain any crucial data that needs to be kept intact between reboots, but it *is* crucial for quite a number of applications that the directory exists and can be written to.

Comment: Wow!!! You're the savior... Thanks a lot.. Can't express the gratefulness in words.. You saved me from formatting.

Answer (score 2):

RPMs that are downloaded and installed by yum are stored in `/var/cache/yum/<repo name>` so just back up those directories if you need to.

EDIT: you have to `set keepcache=1` in `/etc/yum.comf` if you don't want the downloaded rpms to be deleted after successful installation.

Comment: I think it's "yum.conf", not "yum.comf"

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version of yumoncd in this link
http://sourceforge.net/projects/yumoncd/